# Not getting properly formatted legend labels

Tags: plotting, legending

So I have this problem: I'm having to plot the Exponential Integral and another function, but when I come to write the legend to make it to appear in the plot, I don't get the function with the argument, but a reversed writing.

Explaining myself better, this is the code:

```
Plot[{ExpIntegralEi[x], -ExpIntegralEi[-x]}, {x, -2, 3}, 
PlotRange -> {-5, 7}, 
PlotStyle -> {{Darker[Green], Thickness[0.004]}, {Blue, 
Thickness[0.004]}}, 
PlotLegends -> 
Placed[SwatchLegend[{Darker[Green], 
 Blue}, {Style[TraditionalForm[Ei ( x )]], 
 Style[TraditionalForm[Subscript[ℰ, 1](x)]]}, 
LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 10}], {0.6, 0.8}], 
LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 11}]
```

So I want the legend $\text{Ei}(x)$ and $\mathcal{E}_1(x)$.

But what I get is this:

[image]

How can I obtain in the legends the writing $\mathcal{E}_1(x)$ and so on?

Comment: Try `"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[ScriptCapitalE]\), \(1\)]\)(x)"` in an input cell, then copy the out result into the `TraditionalForm[]` box.

Comment: I'm using strings in such cases; go with `{"Ei(x)", "E1(x)"}`.

Comment: For optimum quality use MaTeX https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX

Comment: @Feyre Nothing changes... Still the same. The $x$ comes first -.-

Comment: @corey979 Cool idea! It works now! :)

Comment: You need to use the `"`, it works, I tried it, it's basically the same as what @corey979 suggested, only with making sure it gives a script `E`.

Comment: @Feyre Oh! Thank you again!! ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter the labels in normal Mathematica stardard form and let `TraditionalForm` do the formatting.

```
Plot[{ExpIntegralEi[x], -ExpIntegralEi[-x]}, {x, -2, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> {-5, 7}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Darker[Green], Thickness[0.004]}, {Blue, Thickness[0.004]}},
  PlotLegends ->
    Placed[
      SwatchLegend[
        {Darker[Green], Blue}, 
        {TraditionalForm[Ei[x]], TraditionalForm[Subscript[ℰ, 1][x]]}, 
        LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 10}],
      {0.6, 0.8}],
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 11}]
```

[image: plot]