# Plotting two integrals

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I am having troubles in trying to plot those two integral functions:

$$\text{Ei}(z) = -\int_{-\infty}^z \frac{e^t}{t}\ \text{d}t$$

$$\mathcal{E}_1(z) = \int_z^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t}\ \text{d}t$$

I tried by defining the functions like

```
g[x_] = -E^(t)/t
f[y_] = Integrate[g[x], {x, -Infinity, y}]
Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}]
```

But it doesn't work. That was an example for the first function.

Surely there is something strange in the last command, but it also tells me error because I wrote "infinity" as one of the extrema.

Comment: Your `g[x]` is dependent on `t`, not `x`; you need to assign values to `a` and `b`; and use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) instead of `Set` (`=`). Look also at [`ExpIntegralEi`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpIntegralEi.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a different thread: [Best way to compute the following numerical integral?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130012/best-way-to-compute-the-following-numerical-integral) I showed that the singularities are the source of issues. My approach is to omit them in the integration. Consider

```
g[t_] := -E^t/t
ε = 0.00001;
int0 = NIntegrate[g[x], {x, -Infinity, -ε}]
f[y_] := int0 + NIntegrate[g[x], {x, ε, y}]
plot = Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

The second integral:

```
h[y_] := NIntegrate[g[-t], {t, y, Infinity}]

Plot[h[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: Using the built-in command is even easier: `Plot[-ExpIntegralEi[z], {z, 0, 5}]`

Comment: @bills I mentioned that in a [comment to the question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130230/plotting-two-integrals/130231?noredirect=1#comment351600_130230); due to a number of issues with the OP's approach I decided to elaborate on the basics. Also, the OP [is familiar with](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129292/not-getting-properly-formatted-legend-labels) `ExpIntegralEi`.